# How to update an old Cordova project to last version?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have an old Cordova app (developed by an other). I have many problems with last version of iOS(iOS 11.2.6) and Android(8.0) like white screen, plugins compatibilities and app craches. So I want to update my app to the latest version of Cordova and by the way update plugins.
I tried

```
cordova platform rm android
cordova platform add android
```

I got this errors:

> Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@^6.3.0
>   (node:23932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@^6.3.0
>   Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
>   Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
>   Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
>   npm WARN Invalid version: "1.7"
>   npm WARN No description
>   npm WARN No repository field.
>   npm WARN No README data
>   npm WARN No license field.
>   (node:23932) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I also tried to update plugins using:

```
cordova-check-plugins --update=auto
```

But I got build error (Android Studio)

So I think that the solution is to update my app to the last version of Cordova. Anyone have an idea?

Cordova version 8.0.0

Answer (score 2):

Yes, try updating your app to cordova and then this might work.

Step 1 - sudo npm update -g cordova

Step 2 - cordova platform check

if there is any update for your android platform then the above will give the details of the same.

Step 3 - cordova platform update Android

Try the above steps and this will give you some idea on how to fix this.

Comment: after cordova platform check I got this: android @ 5.1.1; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined
ios @ 4.5.4; current did not install, and thus its version cannot be determined

Comment: I got the same error as above but cordova-android@^7.0.0